# How to load F4V file to Media Display Component in Flash

Tags: flash, action

I am trying to load .F4V file to Media Display Component on button press using Following Script

video.setMedia("support/name.f4v","F4V")

But its not working,

please suggest me solution

Note : With same way if i attach the .flv file its working fine.

But i want good quality Video file so i choose .F4V format

Answer (score 1):

The MediaDisplay component was developed for use with Flash Player 6 and 7, but F4V is supported only for Flash Player 9 and above.  Use the FLVPlayback component instead.

Here's the [related info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS0ED77F00-2006-49aa-8399-92B6D5D8CE00.html#WSD8898A73-ECD8-498c-B200-903CD970DE0B) in the Flash documentation.